# How to emulate Smart Banners in DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) on Android?

Tags: android

I'd like to scale ads to the width of the device from DFP similar to how AdMob claims to scale Smart Banners.  (Smart banners are currently unavailable for DFP.)  Looking at Hierarchy Viewer, I see that a DFP ad is a WebView buried in a few layers of FrameLayout and a RelativeLayout.  Is there a way to find a child WebView without an ID (I have an ID for a parent RelativeLayout), resize the WebView so its size has the same ratio as the ad unit but stretches to the width of the device, and finally scale/zoom the content inside the WebView so it fills the WebView?

For portrait mode, I know the ad is always 320x50 (minus device density).  I haven't decided what to do for landscape yet.

I don't ask for much, do I?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know if what you want is possible, it may be (and probably is) against the Terms of Service with DFP to modify the content like that. Any Ad SDK that uses a WebView will make assumptions based upon how the ad is configured and the ad view size in app to scale ad content appropriately or not. While to you 'forcing' the resize may seem to be innocuous, it may break any specific touch targets (like click here for 'chocolate' vs click here for 'vanilla') which are required of the ad per the advertiser's specification.

In any case you should reach out to DFP or your ad provider to see what can be done. At worst just put the ad on a neutral color background to fill any empty space.

Comment: I don't see this as an issue.  Resizing and zooming the WebView in this manner would ultimately be transparent to the content.  Since what I'm asking for wouldn't modify the content, I don't see how this would be a TOS violation nor would it make touch targets change.  I suspect AdMob Smart Banners operate in a similar manner to what I'm asking for (simply scales the WebView).

Comment: So are you proposing the change the webview and keep the aspect ratio the same (say 320/50) or actually changing the width to fill out say landscape. If you alter the aspect ratio you will alter the expectation of what the content assumes about its container.

Comment: The WebView itself manages the zoom level.  The content is clueless about changes like that because zoom operates on a higher level than the content.  The trick is to get the zoom level just right so the content fills the entire space as before.